# Using wildcards with javascript to return actual values

Tags: javascript, mixpanel, jql

I have written some javascript code so that I can use MixPanel's JQL language.

The code below doesn't work, because * is not a wildcard in Javascript. But I have included it to show where I'd like the wildcard.

I know that I can use the indexOf() function, and startsWith(), but those just return true/false essentially.  How can I return the actual value instead?

```
function main() {
  return Events({
    from_date: '2017-03-01',
    to_date:   '2017-03-31'
  })
      .filter(function(event) { return event.name == "PartsViewed" })
      .filter(function(event){
        return event.properties.PartName =="LTC3784*" && event.properties.PartName == "1EDI60N*";
    })
  .groupBy(["properties.manufacturer"], mixpanel.reducer.count());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to `return` instead of `filter` you need the function `.map`. 
the map function returns what you define, whereas filter just filters the array without modifying the outputs.

```
array
.filter(function(event){
    let name = event.properties.PartName;
    return name.startsWith("LTC3784") || name.startsWith("1EDI60N");
})
.map(function(event) {
    return event.properties.PartName;
})
```

so first you filter properly using existing functionality.
than your